# SVN and 'lite' web servers

Tags: nginx, web-server, svn, lighttpd

I plan to setup and configure SVN server. Think about 'lite' web servers, such as nginx or lighttpd. AFAIK nginx has only limited support for the DAV and does not have SVN module itself. Is it correct information?

If so what about lighttpd? Can SVN be properly configured with lighttpd? Please tell about your experience who has it. What is the best solution.
Thank you.

Comment: Why not just use lightweight svnserve?

Comment: svnserve would be good, but I think about LDAP auth in the future. Does svnserve supports LDAP?

Comment: svnserve supports SASL that can use LDAP as a backend. Also, as alternative, you can configure svn over ssh.

Comment: Why don't you choose Apache2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I'd use the SSH or native transports rather than going over HTTP; but if HTTP is a requirement, having lighttpd proxy back to apache is probably the simplest and most well-documented solution

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the right answer... but I tryed this:

https://solutionexchange.vmware.com/store/products/bitnami-redmine-stack-1-1-3-0-ubuntu-10-10

You can download it and "play it" with VMware player/workstation/ESXi ...

In this appliance you can find [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) and SVN server... we use this solution in our company and we don't have any complain about it.